# date conditionals in less css

Tags: javascript, css, less

I would like to use Less to create some CSS code valid only in a given time-interval.

I'd like to create a mixin like this

```
.showFromTo (@from, @to) when (`new Date().getTime() >= @from && new Date().getTime() <= @to`) {
    width: 100px; //for example
}
```

and then use it more or less like this:

```
.myClass { .showFromTo(`new Date(2014, 01, 02).getTime`, `new Date(2014, 01, 05).getTime()`) }
```

As it is it doesn't work... can anyone give me some help?

Comment: i don't believe guard expressions support arbitrary javascript execution.

Comment: In any case, consider that the Javascript evaluation happens at compile time, so this can only work if you serve the LESS source and let the client compile it (which I wouldn't recommend) or recompile the CSS periodically and remember to bust any cache that you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Couple of Things

1. Passing javascript date info, [January is considered `0` and December `11`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), so you need to account for that.
2. As Stephen Thomas noted, I think he is correct, that javascript expressions in guards is not allowed, so the javascript evaluation must happen before the guard evaluation.

### A Solution

The following accounts for both of these and seems to be functioning correctly:

**LESS**

```
.showFromTo (@startYear, @startMonth, @startDay, @endYear, @endMonth, @endDay) {
  @currentTime: `new Date().getTime()`;
  @start: `new Date(@{startYear}, @{startMonth} - 1, @{startDay}).getTime()`;
  @end: `new Date(@{endYear}, @{endMonth} - 1, @{endDay}).getTime()`;
  @displayCheck: `@{currentTime} >= @{start} && @{currentTime} <= @{end} ? true : false`;
  .display() when (@displayCheck = true) {
    width: 100px; //for example
  }
  .display();
}

.myClass {
  .showFromTo(2014, 1, 1, 2014, 12, 31); //displays if in 2014
}
.myClass2 {
  .showFromTo(2013, 1, 1, 2013, 12, 31); //does not display since we are past 2013
}
```

**CSS Output (for the year 2014)**

```
.myClass {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ScottS for the answer.
I solved it this way:

```
@todayTs: `new Date().getTime()`;
.showFromTo (@fromTs, @toTs) when (@fromTs =< @todayTs) and (@todayTs =<  @toTs) {
    //style
}
```

called with

```
.myClass {
    .showFromTo(`new Date(2014, 00, 03).getTime()`, `new Date(2014, 00, 09).getTime()`);
}
```

In this way the comparison is easier but you need to pass the argument in a more complicated format